# Snippet Changes Not Being Saved

Tags: database, snippets

I'm working on a site in ExpressionEngine which has been causing all sorts of problems, and we thought we had solved most of them, but now have run into a completely new issue which I can't seem to resolve.

We took this project over from another development firm, and when we try to edit any snippets that were created initially those changes are never saved, the snippets code just reverts back to its original state. We are able to create new snippets and edit those without any issues whatsoever, but can edit any of the pre-created templates from the other firm.

I have cleared the cache both through the admin section in EE, and have cleared out the cache folder in system/expressionengine/cache/, but this still does not solve the issue. I thought then that I would just edit the snippet directly in the database in order to make the changes. My changes will save in the database for those snippets, but it still does not change the code in ExpressionEngine. I have verified that any changes that I make to snippets that I have created are being stored in the database, so I'm really confused as to what could be causing the issue, and why even my changes in the database aren't being reflected in the system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked to see if you have either of these addons installed?

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snippet-sync

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snippetssync

They both serve the same functionality; they hook into your snippets when you save them and save them as files (to allow snippets to be in a VCS). Then, when you load a snippet, they hook there as well, and load the snippet from that file. It basically usurps the database call and instead makes the snippets file based.

Comment: No problem; glad you got it figured out!